# Which framework is best to use for creating a multi platform auction app?

Tags: web-apps, database, node.js, mobile, django

I am making an auction application that will run on iOS/Android and the also the web if logged in through a browser. The key feature here is that it will need to be pretty much real time, just like eBay.

I am having a difficult time coming up with a solution for which backend to use, I have used Django in the past along with the Django REST framework for serving mobile devices. For static images I used an S3 bucket to store and keep references to the images in the Django DB (mySQL).

Given that this auction app will need to be fairly real time, I was thinking of using Node, angular, mongodb and express (MEAN) along with featherless and socket.io for real time updates and REST queries.

Now, I wanted to know whether this is a good approach or not, is there a better way of setting up the backend by using something that I am not aware of?

I would like to keep all of the business side logic on the server, would Node be good for that? In Django, I was able to do quite a lot of server side logic in python which was a real plus, but I'm not sure if I can get the same flexibility with Node.

Some other options are firebase by Google, which are fairly real time, but I lack the knowledge to incorporate them into a web app.

I will be using AWS but I don't mind switching to another service if there is need.

Any tips are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: "I would like to keep all of the business side logic on the server" - forget "like", you ***must***.  Since you are going with Angular, then Node.Js sounds like a good decision, unless you are already a PHP coder. Personally, I would not use a NoSql solution; I would go with MySql (perhaps Sqlite).

Comment: @Mawg It looks like we will be going with PHP and laravel/lumen. We were going to work with firebase but it isn't a relational database and it would make queries a huge pain.

Comment: You might want to post that as an answer, and accept it. If you did the research & made that decision, explaining it could help others in future.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned in the [Feathers](https://docs.feathersjs.com/) Slack channel you were interested in Feathers. Ben Awad has a detailed and ongoing YouTube series about building a silent auction app with FeathersJS. Would that be useful?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wVUD9i_LYRw&list=PLN3n1USn4xlnoL-H2VIrzaZhq6uvQppMF